# Rendering Issues between browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, positioning

First, I just started learning html & css about a week ago non-stop like a mad man, and I decided to markup a design I had created a few years ago. I know there are problems with my html and or css, but I'm just starting and trying to use the best practices. I could probably use more shorthand as well. Anyway, I'm rambling on.

The problem I think is, with the absolute positioning I've been using. After quite a bit of troubleshooting, I got Firefox and Chrome on the same page. However, I don't think my layout is liquid and so in Chrome, when I zoom with cmd+, everything goes completely out of whack. No issues in Firefox. And then IE is another monstrosity in itself. Things are rendered all over the place. It's quite unnerving really.

This has been driving me crazy. When things don't work the way you want them to, it's such a struggle, but I'm loving learning web design. If anyone can help, it will be greatly appreciated. I posted my code below...

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div class="container">

        <div id="header">
                <div id="searchBar">
                <form action=""> <small>Search</small> <input type="text" name="search" /></form></div>
                <div id="logo">
                    <h1><a href="">Hell, Michigan<a/></h1>
                </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="" class="active">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Things To See & Do</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Where To Stay</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Plan Your Trip</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!--menu-->
        </div> <!--header-->

        <div id="mainContent">
            <img src="images/main_content.png" width="791" height="209" alt="must see must do" />
        </div>

        <div id="attractions">
            <ul>
                <li id="chapel">
                <h2><a href="" title="Get Hitched in Hell!">Hell Wedding Chapel</a></h2>
                <p>A marriage made in hell can only get better. Tie the knot in Hell's very own
                Wedding Chapel, or renew your vows before hell freezes over!</p></li>

                <li id="run">
                <h2><a href="" title="Run for your lives!">Run Thru Hell</a></h2>
                <p>Not everyone can say that they've run thru hell. Partake in Hell's classic 5 or
                10 mile race, and get a T-shirt that says, <q>I ran thru hell!</q></p></li>

                <li id="lastRides">
                <h2><a href="" title="Your Last Ride Awaits!">Last Rides Reunion</a></h2>
                <p>The annual Last Rides Reunion is a must see event in late September. Witness over 40
                hearses drive through town. Will this be your last ride?</p></li>
            </ul>   
        </div> <!--main content-->

        <div id="subContent">
            <img src="images/sub_content.png" width="791" height="156" alt="choose activity" />
        </div>

        <div id="activities">
            <ul>
                <li id="activitiesOne">
                <h3><a href="" title="Picnic or Hike in Hell!">Picnic or Hike</a></h3></li>

                <li id="activitiesTwo">
                <h3><a href="" title="Canoe or Bike in Hell!">Canoe or Bike</a></h3></li>
            </ul>   
        </div> <!--sub content-->

        <div id="socialContent">
            <h4>Connect with us</h4>
            <ul>
                <li id="twitter">
                <h5><a href="">Hell Michigan on Twitter</a></h5></li>

                <li id="facebook">
                <h5><a href="">Hell Michigan on Facebook</a></h5></li>

                <li id="youtube">
                <h5><a href="">Hell Michigan on YouTube</a></h5></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!--social content-->

        <div id="footer">
            <p>&copy; Hell Michigan &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="privacy.htm">Privacy Policy</a> |
                <a href="terms.htm">Terms and Conditions</a>
            </p>
        </div> <!--footer-->
    </div> <!--containter-->
</div> <!--main-->
</body>
</html>
```

---

**CSS:**

```
/*
    Hell Michigan Demo Page
    Design & Markup by Khoi Nguyen
*/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Rockwell, Georgia, serif;    
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;          
    padding: 0;         
}



#menu a {
    color: #fff
}

#main {
    width: 791px;       
    margin: 0 auto;     
    background: #fff;       
    position: relative;
}

#header {
    height: 118px;  
    background-color: #fff;
}

/* 
    Search-Bar
*/

#header #searchBar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 595px;
    top: 20px;
}

#logo a:link {
    height: 45px;
    width: 478px;
    display: block;         
    text-indent: -9999em;   
    background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat left bottom;
    border: 0;           
    padding: .3em .3em;
    margin: 0 .3em;
}

/* 
    Navigation
*/

#header #menu {        
    left: 791px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

#menu ul {               
    color: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5ex;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 0 1px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu li {               
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu li a:link {

    display: block;         
    color: #fff;            
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: 0 0 0 0; 
    margin-right: 1px;
    width: 139px;
    line-height: 31px;
    background: url(../images/navigation_dual.jpg) no-repeat left bottom;
    border: none;          
}

#menu li a:hover {
    color: #000;         
    background-position: left top;     
}

#menu li a.active {
    height: 31px;
    width: 80px;
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    background: url(../images/home.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#menu li a.active {
    cursor: default;
}

/* 
    Main-Content
*/

#mainContent img {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: .5em;
}

#attractions ul  #chapel a:link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 129px;
    left: 328px;
    width: 151px;
    height: 201px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(../images/chapel_dual.png) no-repeat left bottom;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}

#attractions ul #chapel a:hover {
    background-position: left top;     
}

#attractions ul  #run a:link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 129px;
    left: 482px;
    width: 151px;
    height: 201px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(../images/run_dual.jpg) no-repeat left bottom;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}

#attractions ul #run a:hover {
    background-position: left top;     
}

#attractions ul  #lastRides a:link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 129px;
    left: 636px;
    width: 151px;
    height: 201px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(../images/last_rides_dual.jpg) no-repeat left bottom;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}

#attractions ul #lastRides a:hover {
    background-position: left top;      
}

#attractions ul {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: auto;
}

#chapel p {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: .8em;
    color: gray;
    top: 340px;
    left: 328px;
    width: 142px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#run p {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: .8em;
    color: gray;
    top: 340px;
    left: 482px;
    width: 142px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#lastRides p {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: .8em;
    color: gray;
    top: 340px;
    left: 636px;
    width: 142px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* 
    Sub-Content
*/

#activities ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#subContent img {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 106px;
}

#activities ul  #activitiesOne a:link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 448px;
    left: 4.5px;
    width: 197px;
    height: 148px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(../images/picnic_hike_dual.png) no-repeat left bottom;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}

#activities ul #activitiesOne a:hover {
    background-position: left top;      
}

#activities ul  #activitiesTwo a:link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 448px;
    left: 209px;
    width: 304px;
    height: 148px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(../images/canoe_bike_dual.png) no-repeat left bottom;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}

#activities ul #activitiesTwo a:hover {
    background-position: left top;      
}
```

Comment: Try using position:relative and position:absolute as a last resort. I rarely use those properties as I can do almost all my positioning with float's.

Answer (score 1):

Good luck with learning, it will all come into place with practice, and IE is the pain for everyone, so that's normal as well:)

First thing you could do is get into habit of always putting a "reset css" code at the very top of your css file - here's one very good you can use:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/#code

What it does is kinda getting all the browsers to be on the "same page" when it comes to displaying stuff.

Then, I'd suggest you try starting from blank page, adding one by one element, and checking each one to see does it behave right in all browsers, and tweaking as needed. Eventually you'll start writing code instinctively knowing how to do things the right way, and will need way less checking.

One more thing many developers do: Choose your "primary browser", the one you'll develop things in, make sure things look good in it, and then check and tweak stuff for other browsers. For this approach to make sense, your primary browser needs to be a modern, standards-compliant one, like Firefox (Safari and Chrome are ok too). And then you develop for IE last, as it's expected that it will misbehave and need special treatment (which you can give it using conditional comments: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Another useful link with fixes for stuff you'll encounter: 
http://www.positioniseverything.net/

For learning more about liquid layouts, check this out:
http://www.cssliquid.com/

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely make use of those bookmarks. I didn't think to make use of the reset before I started, but it'll definitely be good in getting all browsers on the same page in regard to layout. I keep telling myself that it will all come together naturally for me with time. It's difficult starting out as with anything worthwhile learning. There's just so much to know, but I'm confident that it will come together in time so long as I keep workin' my ass off.